# Media library is in portrait orientation while app is landscape when uploading picture

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When you add an image from the Stack Exchange iOS app, the media library is rendered in portrait orientation, even when the app itself is in landscape.

To duplicate, turn your iPad so it is in landscape orientation. Create a question. Add an image. Select "Photo Library."

As an unrelated aside, I noticed this issue while reporting a different bug. Making people wait for 20 minutes before they can report additional bugs seems a bit counter productive in an app beta test.

[image: Why do I need to wait 20 min to report another bug?]

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the image picker to display in a popover, so it can display correctly while in landscape. (The native iOS Photo Library picker does not support landscape as a fullscreen modal).

[image]

This change will be available in **version 1.1.0.131**.

Regarding the 20 minute time limit – unfortunately that's a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as the StackExchange API imposes a time restriction on how often questions can be posted in order to prevent spamming/abuse.

Comment: Cool. I'll check it in 1.1.0.131. I figured the 20 minute time limit was related to spam/abuse.... but at the same time it does seem a bit counterproductive when doing beta tests. Probably not an easy change to make, if it's even one that should be made. Just wanted to mention....